# How to Dynamically Create and Expose a New REST Endpoint In Code (on the fly) for a Custom Loopback Model

Tags: rest, dynamic, loopbackjs, strongloop

We're developing a SaaS accounting product that uses the Loopback REST framework and allows authenticated end users to create new tables in their own database instance (MySQL or PostgreSQL).

**QUESTION**: How can we create a new root level Looback REST endpoint in code (on the fly) to access the new table? For example if the user adds a new table named 'cars' we need to expose a new root level REST endpoint in code called  **'/api/cars'** that uses the persisted model to provide full CRUD capability without restarting the Node.js instance and without writing JSON files to disk.

**NOTE**: This question is similar to [LoopBack: How to Dynamically Create Custom REST Endpoints In Code (On The Fly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932828/loopback-how-to-dynamically-create-custom-rest-endpoints-in-code-on-the-fly). However that question and answer only dealt with the creation of a new model in code and did not address how to expose a new, custom root level REST endpoint to access a new model.

I found this [interesting post](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular-cli/issues/27) that seems to be headed in the right direction, but we're not sure how to create a new root REST endpoint and then wire it to a dynamically generated model. Also, **we're using Kendo rather than Angular**:

```
angular.module('my-app-module')
  .config(function(LoopBackResourceProvider) {
    // Change the URL where to access the LoopBack REST API server
    LoopBackResourceProvider.setUrlBase('http://api.example.com/');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution we ended up with:

// server\boot.js

```
var ds = app.datasources['mysql'];    
ds.createModel('transactiontype', {
    rowid: {
        type: Number,
        id: true
    },
    transactiontypeid: String,
    description: String,
    active: Number
});    
let model = ds.getModel('transactiontype');    
app.model(model, { public: true });
```

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while but this isn't working for me anymore... Has anything changed that anybody might be aware of? Still using Loopback 2.x (:

Comment: What's happening? What are the error's that you're getting?

Comment: I actually finally figured it out.. in oder to expose it to rest now you need to create it with `var MyModel = app.loopback.createModel('ModelName');` and you can't do ds.createModel (you still need app.model at the end but that alone won't expose it if you do ds.createModel)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is [create a new model](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#datasource-prototype-createmodel) on the fly attached to a datasource. Once the model is created, all endpoints will be available to hit it!

```
var ds = app.datasources['my-data'];
ds.createModel('Car', {
  model: String,
  make: String,
  year: number
});
```