# How To Create REST Endpoints and Remote Methods in Loopback at Runtime Without Restarting Node?

Tags: api, rest, runtime, loopbackjs, strongloop

We have successfully created REST remote methods in code in Loopback using a boot script which has has allowed us to completely eliminate the JSON schema files. However, our ultimate goal is be able to **create a new REST endpoint and remote methods at runtime, on the fly after startup at any time**. In the example below the new endpoint ('newEndPoint') should be created by calling /api/example/createNewMethod, but 'newMethod' is not being exposed in the REST API. Here's the code:

```
// **************
// Initialize 'createNewMethod' in a boot script. (THIS IS WORKING)
// **************
model.createNewMethod = function createNewMethod(data, callback) {

    // **************
    // Initialize 'newMethod' @ runtime by calling createNewMethod
    // **************

    console.log("Initializing 'newMethod'...");

    // This is called by calling /api/example/newMethod
    model.newMethod = function newMethod(data, callback) {

        // THIS IS NOT WORKING
        console.log("'newMethod' works!")

        // Return from newMethod()
        callback({return: true});
    }    

    model.remoteMethod(
        'newMethod',
        {
            http: { verb: 'get' },
            returns: [
                { arg: 'eventinfo', type: 'data' },
            ]
        }
    );

    // Return from createNewMethod()
    callback({return: true});    
}

model.remoteMethod(
    'createNewMethod',
    {
        http: { verb: 'get' },
        returns: [
            { arg: 'eventinfo', type: 'data' }
        ]
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. We can allow users to add new tables or add new columns to existing tables without restarting node and the exposing the changes via a Loopback REST endpoint by simply recreating the end-point. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133409/4134796)